# Aligning Kivy objects using pure Python

Tags: python, kivy

I can't seem to figure out alignment using pure Python code. My understanding is that we reference `root` to get relational alignment. However, I haven't been able to get it to work. This code compiles, runs, and then places the button in the bottom left corner. At the 0,0 coords. What am I missing here?

```
class ContainerView(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContainerView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        new = Button()
        new.text = "username"
        new.size = (50,50)
        new.color = [3/255,50/255,155/255,1]
        new.size_hint = [0.5,0.5]
        new.center = self.center ###This line
        self.add_widget(new)


class ScoreboardApp(App):
    def build(self):
        cView = ContainerView()
        cView.build()
        return cView
```

Update:

After a bunch of trial and error I found that setting the window size and then aligning in the .kv file works, but I don't know fully know why. If I log the window size to the console it still gives me the actual dimensions of my computer.

*main.py:*

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

### Set window size
Window.size = (1440, 800)

### Set size_hint in draw function
class ClientScoreboard(GridLayout):
    containerView = ContainerView()
    numberOfRows = 0
    numberOfColumns = 0

    def buildClientScoreboard(self):
        self.cols = self.numberOfColumns
        self.rows = self.numberOfRows
        self.size_hint = (0.75, 0.85)
```

*.kv*

```
<ContainerView>
    ClientScoreboard:
        id: client_scoreboard
        x: 375
        y: self.parent.height - self.height - 25.0
```

I suspect it has something to do with referencing `FloatLayout` as the center point.

Comment: To what do you want the button aligned to?

Comment: the center ... see the line that he put ### this line

Answer (score 0):

it (your floatlayout) does not know the window size ... so it uses the default size of (100,100) ... so it centers the button there

try telling your float layout its size

```
cView = ContainerView(size=(500,350))
```

Comment: I would have thought so as well but it seems you have to reference the actual window.